# How do I make a 3 dotted brush

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I'm interested in making a dotted brush. Am I able to do that?

I'm also interested in making a dotted line brush, but a row of three lines of dots instead of just one. Is that making sense?

I'd like to be able to draw one dotted line and have identical copies of the line parallel to the line drawn. Is this possible in either Photoshop or Illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

In Illustrator......

Create the dotted path by checking `Dashed` on the **Stroke Panel** and entering a dash length equal to or smaller than the weight of the stroke. Also ensure you tick the `Round Caps` and `Round Joints` options.

Then duplicate the stroke in the **Appearance Panel** and choose `Effect > Path > Offset path` and enter the amount of offset you want.

[image]

If your path is a *closed* path, you'll need to create another copy of the stroke in the **Appearance Panel** and apply a different offset amount to that second copy. Basically, for open paths you only need 1 duplicate. For closed paths you need 2 duplicates.

You can then drag this path to the **Graphic Styles Panel** and easily *reapply* it to *any* path by selecting a path and then clicking the style.

Photoshop simply doesn't have the options to do this as easily. You *can* draw a path and make it dotted in Photoshop, especially in the Creative Cloud versions via the vector stroke options. It's very similar to the Illustrator method above. However, for copies of the path you'd have to draw one path, then manually duplicate that path for any other paths you wanted. You coudl try a brush in Photoshop with a higher degree of `Spacing` dynamics, but that's s

Comment: You can use the pen tool, the pencil tool, the line tool. A brush won't work.